# Ubuntu docker running docker

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  ubuntu:
    image: 'ubuntu:16.04'
    ports:
      - '22:22'
```

When start this, the container seems to crash, the following are the logs that I see:

```
Attaching to playground_ubuntu_1
ubuntu_1  | Error grabbing logs: EOF

playground_ubuntu_1 exited with code 0
```

My host OS is Ubuntu 16.04 with `Docker version 17.12.0-ce, build c97c6d6`.

All of my other containers seem to start normally, but this one just flat out fails on boot.

Comment: Should add a `CMD` to execute something. 'ubuntu:16.04' image by itself does not execute anything.

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu can you elaborate more?

Comment: The exact same thing as ~yamenk answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal. When you start a container it will run as long as the main process started inside the container is still running.

This process is specified using the `CMD` command inside a Dockerfile. The ubuntu image does not have a `CMD` as it is intended to be used as a building block for other docker images.
Thus when you run this image without specifying a command, it exits successful as can be seen from the 0 exit code.

If you want this image to stay alive just for testing, you can specify a command that will keep it living.

```
version: '2'
services:
  ubuntu:
    image: 'ubuntu:16.04'
    ports:
      - '22:22'
    command: "tail -f /dev/null"
```

Answer (score 3):

Exit status in log `playground_ubuntu_1 exited with code 0` shows that its expected. In order to make a container up & running for long, you need to give/define a foreground process for your container. I have momentarily edited your compose file -

```
version: '2'
services:
  ubuntu:
    image: 'ubuntu:16.04'
    ports:
      - '22:22'
    command: "tail -f /dev/null"
```

Now you run it -

`$ docker-compose up -d && docker ps`

Your container is up & running now.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you already use port `22` on your host. Try to bind container `22` port to another port on your host, for example `2222`

```
version: '2'
services:
  ubuntu:
    image: 'ubuntu:16.04'
    ports:
      - '2222:22'
```